# Highcharts: setting spacing dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I would like to set the spacingRight dynamically after drill down.

Here is the function i am using to switch to the drill down chart:

```
function setChart(options) {
        chart.series[0].remove(false);
        chart.addSeries({
            type: options.type,
            name: options.name,
            data: options.data,
            color: options.color || 'white'
        }, false);
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(options.categories, false);
        chart.options.spacingRight = 35; //not working
        chart.redraw();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workaround is to overwrite (you were close!) that options and set dirty box:

```
    chart.options.chart.spacingRight = 5;
    chart.isDirtyBox = true;
    chart.redraw();
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/208/

Comment: Works perfect, even in IE8, many thanks! How did you find "isDirtyBox" and what is it for?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately dynamical modification of spacingRight parameter is not available, only when you destroy chart and create new instantion, then you can modify this option. You can request your suggestion in our uservoice system http://highcharts.uservoice.com/